# How to escape a shell command to run it from php

Tags: php, bash, shell, sed

Hi there I have a sed command that I need to run from a php file, the command runs just fine at shell, but from php gives apache errors saying the problem are the semicolon, I tried escaping them all, I also tried escaping the curly brakets, then there is no error at apache but the command don't do as expected, here's the command

```
$cmd = "sed -n -i '/ENDSNUMB/{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}' ./taggedfiles/$tagfile";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: Is `$tagfile` a PHP variable you want to concatenate or do you literally want to pass that to your command?

Comment: $tagfile is the file where to perform the sed replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In double quotes, PHP tries to parse inline variables into the string. Your `$` is the problem.

Try using single quotes and escape the ones in your string like this:

```
$cmd = 'sed -n -i \'/ENDSNUMB/{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}\' ./taggedfiles/' . $tagfile;
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Be very careful with parsing variables into shell code though. Without escaping it properly you might be vulnerable for [Command Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) attacks.

Comment: Also, the good point is to use the `exec()` instead of `shell_exec()` function because you can't check errors (returned code) with `shell_exec()`

Comment: @Ivar It gives no apache error but no change at the file neither

Comment: @AndrésChandía I've updated my answer after your answer to Magnus' comment.

Comment: @Ivar thanks but it didn't run as expected... here's my command now: `$cmd = 'sed -n -i \'/ENDSNUMB/{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}\' ./taggedfiles/' + $tagfile;
shell_exec($cmd);`

Comment: Yes my bad, string concatenation in PHP goes with the `.` operator. Not the `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `escapeshellcmd` to do this for all the replacement values...
From the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

```
<?php
// We allow arbitrary number of arguments intentionally here.
$command = './configure '.$_POST['configure_options'];

$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);

shell_exec($escaped_command);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it makes no difference